# How to create a directory in wix?

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, wix3.5

My requirement is to create a directory in **programdata/test/example**. How can I do that in wix?

Answer (score 74):

Define the folder like this:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="TestFolder" Name="test">
            <Directory Id="ExampleFolder" Name="example" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

The important part here is the `CommonAppDataFolder` Id, which is known by Windows installer. You can find the full list of known system folders in the [Windows Installer Property Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx#system_folder_properties).

If you install any files to that folder, it will be created implicitly. If not, you can force it to be created by installing a component like this:

```
<Component Id="CreateTestFolder" Directory="ExampleFolder" Guid="PUT-RANDOM-GUID-HERE">
    <CreateFolder />
</Component>
```

Comment: I get this error when using it: `error CNDL0205: The Directory with Id 'CommonAppDataFolder' is not a valid root directory. ` (plus a bit more about only having a single root directory per product). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @noelicus: in windows installer, the top-level parent directory must always be TARGETDIR. I'll update my answer to clarify this.

Comment: @WimCoenen Is it possible to copy folder/files1..to..files5 during the installation of wix installer.

Comment: @Royal: comments are not the right place to ask new questions. Just post a new stackoverflow question.

Comment: @WimCoenen I have raised the new SO question please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020130/how-to-copy-folder-files1-to-files5-during-the-installation-of-wix-installer

Answer (score 17):

Under `<Product>` you can enter:

```
   <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
      <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="CommonAppXXXX" Name="test">
          <Directory Id="CommonAppYYYY" Name="example">
            <Component Id="CreateProgramDataZZZ" Guid="ABC-ETC">
              <CreateFolder />
            </Component>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

And reference the component `CreateProgramDataZZZ` in your `feature`.

It can also be helpful to set permissions on the directory like this:

```
<CreateFolder>
    <util:PermissionEx User="Users" GenericAll="yes" />
</CreateFolder>
```

(in place of `<CreateFolder />`)

Comment: any one have idea create folder and move files in same folder?

Comment: use the WIX_ACCOUNT_USERS on User=, as the account will change on other languages.

Answer (score 1):

this will create folder for you...

```
<Directory Id="DIR_ID" Name="DIR_NAME">
    <Component Guid="GUID" Id="id" KeyPath="no" NeverOverwrite="no" Permanent="no" Location="local">
        <CreateFolder>
            <util:PermissionEx CreateChild="yes" CreateFile="yes" Delete="yes" Read="yes" ReadAttributes="yes" ReadExtendedAttributes="yes" ReadPermission="yes" Traverse="yes" GenericRead="yes" GenericWrite="yes" User="Everyone" />
        </CreateFolder>
    </Component>
</Directory>
```